# Determine background status with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, ios13, appdelegate, nsnotificationcenter, uiscenedelegate

When using SwiftUI with iOS 13+, the **traditional means of determining background state no longer work**. For example:

- AppDelegate methods `applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)` and `applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)` do not get called.
- Notifications `didEnterBackgroundNotification`, `willEnterForegroundNotification`, `didBecomeActiveNotification` and `willResignActiveNotification` do not get sent.

As an alternative, there are `UIWindowSceneDelegate` callbacks: `sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene)`, `sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene)`, `sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene)`, `sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene)`

The problem with these replacements is that they are specific to one of multiple scenes that are entering and leaving the foreground.  They do not provide a simple and clean way to determine if the entire app is in the foreground or background.

**Determining app foreground/background status is important for reasons that have nothing to do with the user interface.**  Some iOS features fail silently when the app is not in the foreground (wildcard bluetooth scanning and iBeacon transmission are two examples.)  I often develop iOS frameworks that have no user interface whatsoever, so **I need a way to determine app background/foreground state that does not rely on pasting a bunch of boilerplate code in the `UIWindowSceneDelegate`** -- it is not reasonable for me to ask somebody using my framework to do that.

Are there any straightforward ways to determine the apps's foreground/background status on iOS 13 with SwiftUI?

Comment: Does `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in` not work for you?

Comment: @pawello222, I stand corrected.  Contrary to what I say in my question, the four notifications I say do not fire still do fire.  I was certain last time I tried that didn't happen, but apparently I was wrong.  If you make this an answer I will gladly accept.

Comment: in the WWDC19 [Introducing Multiple Windows on iPad](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/212/) there is an explanation of this possible "discrepancy"; right around 17:06 there is a chart but the whole talk is very informative

Comment: We need an explanation about the case those functions did not trigger.

Comment: As is common in science and engineering, sometimes an observed test result cannot be reproduced.  There are countless reasons why this might have been true -- the tester may have made a mistake, or there may have been other conditions not noted that polluted the test case.  If you can't reproduce the result of an experiment the result should be discounted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `UIApplication` notifications in SwiftUI as well:

- `didEnterBackgroundNotification`
- `willEnterForegroundNotification`
- `didBecomeActiveNotification`
- `willResignActiveNotification`

Here is an example:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
    // active
}

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
    // inactive
}
```

Comment: This is correct.  My statement in my question that these did not work was in error.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way is not to use NotificationCenter at all but rather use the “scenePhase” Environment object. Can be used in any SwiftUI view that needs to see the state or the entire app.

```
@main

struct ExampleApp: App {
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
                .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
                    switch phase {
                    case .background:
                        print("App is background")
                    case .inactive:
                        print("App is inactive")
                    case .active:
                        print("App is active")
                    @unknown default:
                        print("Phase is unknown")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct way to handle events in SwiftUI is to use the [onReceive](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onreceive(_:perform:)) method.

```swift
Text("Hello, World!")
    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification)) { _ in
        // Action
    }
```

Comment: While the above may work great for a specific scene, the question is about how do determine the foreground/background state for the entire application across many scenes

Answer (score 1):

### SwiftUI

While you are within any **SwiftUI instances (View, App or custom Scene)**, Apple recommends using the 'scenePhase' Environment variable to access the current app's scene phase. The 'ScenePhase' enum currently contains following three cases. For a more comprehensive understanding, I suggest checking out the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scenephase)

- Active
- Inactive
- Background.

[There's a minor change in the 'onChange' method behaviour. From iOS 17.*, you can now retrieve both the old and new values within the 'onChange' modifier.]

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onChange(of: scenePhase) { oldPhase, newPhase in
                    switch newPhase {
                    case .background:
                        print("SchenePhase: Background from \(oldPhase)")
                    case .inactive:
                        print("SchenePhase: Inactive from \(oldPhase)")
                    case .active:
                        print("SchenePhase: Active/Foreground from \(oldPhase)")
                    @unknown default:
                        print("SchenePhase: Unknown scene phase \(newPhase) from \(oldPhase)")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

### Swift

However, if you find yourself within **Swift instances in a SwiftUI project**, you'll need to observe UIApplication notifications to capture the app's state.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
    // active
}

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
    // inactive
}

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
    // Background
}

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
    // Foreground
}
```