# SwiftUI application lifecycle

Tags: ios, swiftui, badge

In my first SwiftUI app, I have Remote Notifications and Background Processes enabled.
I did add an AppDelegate class, to support notification.

The notifications set the app badge to an appropriate value.

Since this app has these background modes enabled, several lifecycle events are not working:

- `applicationDidBecomeActive`
- `applicationWillResignActive`
- `applicationDidEnterBackground`
- `applicationWillEnterForeground`

Question: where/how do I reset the badge?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62840614/12299030?

Comment: Those messages come to the _scene_ delegate, not the _application_ delegate.

Answer (score 14):

Here is how you can observe `didBecomeActiveNotification`:

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)) { _ in
                    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
                }
        }
    }
}
```

You can observe other notifications in the same way.

---

Alternatively you can use an `@EnvironmentObject` to track the application state:

- [How can I use a method without any page transition or any reboot app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63765784/8697793)

Answer (score 4):

```
@Environment (\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
                    if newPhase == .active {
                        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Correct, but better explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818327/determine-background-status-with-swiftui

Answer (score 4):

### SwiftUI

While you are within any SwiftUI instance (View, App or custom Scene), Apple recommends using the **'scenePhase' Environment** variable to access the current app's scene phase. The 'ScenePhase' enum currently contains following three cases. For a more comprehensive understanding, I suggest checking out the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scenephase)

- Active
- Inactive
- Background.

[There's a minor change in the 'onChange' method behaviour. From iOS 17.*, you can now retrieve both the old and new values within the 'onChange' modifier.]

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onChange(of: scenePhase) { oldPhase, newPhase in
                    switch newPhase {
                    case .background:
                        print("SchenePhase: Background from \(oldPhase)")
                    case .inactive:
                        print("SchenePhase: Inactive from \(oldPhase)")
                    case .active:
                        print("SchenePhase: Active/Foreground from \(oldPhase)")
                    @unknown default:
                        print("SchenePhase: Unknown scene phase \(newPhase) from \(oldPhase)")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

### Swift

However, if you find yourself within Swift instance in a SwiftUI project, you'll need to observe **UIApplication notifications** to capture the app's state.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
    // active
}

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
    // inactive
}

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
    // Background
}

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
    // Foreground
}
```